# Force on an Aluminium plate in a 1T field?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetics

I am thinking of using a magnetic field to damp mechanical oscillations/noise in an Aluminium swing arm. The problem is that I do not even know how to calculate ballpark numbers for the effects I am looking for.

Is there a (reasonably) simple way of doing the calculation, given speed of the arm, magnetic field strength, conductance/resistivity of bulk Aluminium and dimensions etc? If it will simplify things, assume the arm is totally enveloped by a uniform field.

It is important that nothing touch the arm. I would encase it in a pressurized Xenon atmosphere if I could, but other solutions are also not possible

Comment: Are you sure this is the right approach?  Isn't aluminum transparent to magnetic fields?

Comment: @SteveSh movement of the aluminium will create eddy currents in the aluminium and they will seek to stop movement.

Comment: Ah, right!  Forgot about the eddy current.

Comment: Is this swing arm moving over some distance? Because the magnetic effects require close proximity.  How about a bath of mineral oil? Flexible coupling? Machining to allow flex? Material other than (rigid) aluminum? Added/removed mass?

Comment: check out youtube videos pf people dropping strong magnets down copper tubes, the glacial progress downwards will give you an order of magnitude estimate of the effects. As a not very helpful observation, I'm playing with a torsional pendulum at the moment with a flat plate alli armature, and bring an ex-MO ferrite ring magnet (<< 1T field ) up to within a few mm briskly repels it significantly (that's briskly and significantly in SI units!)

Comment: @Neil_UK Mine will be moving at microns per second, and nano-everything elsewhere

Comment: @DirkBruere OK, curious now, what are you doing? I'm doing a Cavendish-type gravity experiment.

Comment: It depends if this swing arm carries something like a disk head or a motorbike wheel; I doubt you can generate enough force to make any substantial difference in a vehicle suspension.

Comment: @Neil_UK Working on trying to remove noise from a microbalance that resolves to 50ng

Comment: Can you attach an explicit 'damper' to the arm, rather than using the arm itself? If so, then a hollow cylinder that slides inside where the voice coil would go in a loudspeaker magnet would give you a) high coupling b) high field c) something that's easy to calculate

Comment: @Neil_UK Might try something like that, but initially I will just use a Nd magnet and check it out. Field leakage might make the idea non viable

Comment: You say that you are working on something tiny, you may need tiny magnets too. Good conductors produce eddy currents to oppose changes in their internal magnetic fields. The typical science experiment uses a large conductor and a small magnet, and the eddy currents oppose moving the magnet relative to the conductor as this increases the magnetic field in some places and reduces it in others. If you have a relatively small conductor in a larger uniform field, I **think** that there will be minimal drag as you move it around, until you try to remove it (or possibly rotate it).

Answer (score 1):

The force of damping is proportional to velocity much like the force due to viscous flow. In both cases, the constant of proportionality is typically determined experimentally, or possibly by numerical simulation. It does seem as though it should be possible to calculated from material, geometry, and magnetic field. But in fact, like the force due to wind resistance, it is a difficult calculation to perform in all but the most trivial cases. The coefficient of wind resistance of automobiles is determined by experiment or computational fluid dynamics.

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather handwavy answer, but I am going to go with the above suggestion relating the drag to fluid dynamics. From crude observation with the materials at hand it *looks* like something dropped into water. For my application I can then reduce the problem to one parameter, viscosity.

Answer (score 0):

If the arm is immersed in a uniform field then the damping effects are tiny.  You need variations in the field so that the motion of the arm results in changes in the flux.  It is these changes in flux that produce the large eddy currents that damp the motion.

Kirk McDonald at Princeton analyzes the damping effects on a copper cube immersed in a uniform field and notes that if the field is uniform that the damping effects are small:  *"For parameters typical of laboratory experiments, the time constant τ is larger than the age of the Universe."*

[kirkmcd.princeton.edu/examples/eddy.pdf](http://kirkmcd.princeton.edu/examples/eddy.pdf)

Comment: Interesting. This gives me an idea for a much simpler variation of the experiment I was planning

Answer (score 0):

You could ballpark it by calculating the voltage induced in the arm (consider it a loop ?) due to its velocity cutting the magnetic flux; then using the resistance, calculate the current (which may be quite large), then the (electrical) power generated which will represent a damping force.

Comment: The key here is that the arm is immersed in a *uniform* field, hence as it moves there is no changing flux through the arm.  Check out Kirk McDonald's analysis that I linked in my answer.